# Deriving equality for Julia structs with mutable members

Tags: struct, julia, immutability, equality

In the Julia code below, we have equality not working for `T{BigInt}`, due to `BigInt` being a mutable struct. `==` is explicitly defined by `BigInt` for themselves, however.

```
julia> struct T{X}
           x :: X
       end

julia> T{Int64}(1) == T{Int64}(1), T{Int64}(1) === T{Int64}(1)
(true, true)

julia> T{BigInt}(1) == T{BigInt}(1), T{BigInt}(1) === T{BigInt}(1)
(false, false)

julia> T{BigInt}(1).x == T{BigInt}(1).x, T{BigInt}(1).x === T{BigInt}(1).x
(true, false)
```

Is there a way to either:

- autogenerate an `==` for these sorts of structs which just recurses `==` on each field,
- or have immutable versions of mutable structs as members (as with `const` in C++), other than using an immutable equivalent to `BigInt`?

My goal is to avoid boilerplate in a package with a large number of such structs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
function my_equals(a::S, b::S) where S
    for name in fieldnames(S)
        if getfield(a, name) != getfield(b, name)
            return false
        end
    end
    return true
end
```

I tried overloading `==` via

```
import Base.==

function ==(a::S, b::S) where S
    for name in fieldnames(S)
        if getfield(a, name) != getfield(b, name)
            return false
        end
    end
    return true
end
```

That has the intended behavior, but (unsurprisingly) seems to break things (i.e. you can't even call `exit()` after redefining `==` like that).

If you want to use `==`, then you could have all your custom `struct`s inherit from some abstract type, like this:

```
abstract type Z end

struct T{X} <: Z
    x::X
end

struct S{X} <: Z
    x::X
    y::X
end

import Base.==

function ==(a::V, b::V) where V <: Z
    for name in fieldnames(V)
        if getfield(a, name) != getfield(b, name)
            return false
        end
    end
    return true
end
```

Then you can use

```
julia> T{BigInt}(1) == T{BigInt}(1)
true

julia> S{BigInt}(2, 5) == S{BigInt}(2, 5)
true

julia> T{BigInt}(1) == T{BigInt}(2)
false

julia> S{BigInt}(2, 5) == S{BigInt}(2, 3)
false
```

That doesn't interfere with existing `==`.